# ¿como convierto este valor /Date(585115200000)/ a formato fecha?

Tags: javascript, json

Hola comunidad necesito ayuda en lo siguiente: utilizando mi código, ¿Cómo podría convertir este valor `/Date(585115200000)/` a la fecha correcta?

```
function buscarSeccionJS() {
var id_supervisor = $('#id_supervisor').val();
$.ajax({
    url: '/ingreso/buscarSeccionSupervisor',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: { id_supervisor: id_supervisor },
    success: function (respuesta) {
        $('#obtener_seccion').val(respuesta.seccion);
        $('#fecha_ingreso').val(respuesta.fecha_obtenida);
    }
})
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el origen de ese valor de fecha? No es evidente su formato, por lo que no es trivial la conversión

Comment: @Alfabravo el valor de esa fecha corresponde a otra tabla que tiene un valor de fecha y al recuperar dicho valor con este codigo me entrega /Date(585115200000)/

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con el siguiente código:

```
let jsonDate = "/Date(585115200000)/";
let date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
console.log(date);
```

La función substr() elimina el texto /Date( y parseInt() obtiene el número entero e ignora los símbolos del final. El resultado lo pasamos al constructor Date y listo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero ¿como lo ajusto a mi código ya que ese valor date  $('#fecha_ingreso')  varia dependiendo la id_supervisor seleccionado?

Comment: Solo haz que jsonDate sea igual a el id de tu elemento: ```let jsonDate = $('#fecha_ingreso').val();```

Comment: Si fue útil por favor marca la respuesta como la correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve que buscar bastante en SO en inglés, pero encontré que es un viejo formato para Microsoft JSON.

Para darle formato, se puede usar:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(respuesta.fecha_obtenida.substr(6)));
```

Aunque el OP de la pregunta dice que lo resolvió con

```
formatJSONDate(Date(respuesta.fecha_obtenida));
...
function formatJSONDate(jsonDate) {
  var newDate = dateFormat(jsonDate, "mm/dd/yyyy");
  return newDate;
}
```

Porque, esencialmente, se trata de un valor en segundos. Algunos prueban con expresiones regulares para dejar el valor entero y crear el nuevo Date

```js
var dateString = "/Date(585115200000)/";
var seconds = parseInt(dateString.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]+)[^+]\//i, "$1"));
var date = new Date(seconds);
console.log(date);
```

Fuente (la respuesta aceptada sugiere mejores formas de manejar fechas): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date

Más info [aquí](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y apoyo, pero el valor en la tabla es 17/07/1988 como ajusto mi código para que ya no aparezca así /Date(585115200000)/ igual estoy probando con lo que me envió, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: @jaimev Por eso mismo. Lee de nuevo. Cuando haces respuesta.fecha_obtenida sale el /Date(xxxxx)/ que dices. Hay que procesarlo como dice cualquiera de la sdos respuestas.

Comment: Quizás se ria pero soy novato en esto y no logro aplicar la solución, si me pudiera orientar el como aplicarlo se lo agradecería de gran manera.

Comment: @jaimev amigo, no sé cómo hacer más explícita la aplicación de la solución que dan en la pregunta original.